# How do i reload data in a tableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, ios5

Every time i reload data inside a button click the app crashes.
Here is the code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ResultViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,      
UITableViewDataSource> {
NSMutableArray *listData;
NSMutableArray *listLocation;
NSMutableArray *listPostDate;
NSMutableArray *listLogo;
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *uiNavigationBar;
IBOutlet UITableView *uiTableView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listLocation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listPostDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listLogo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *uiTableView;

-(IBAction)done;
-(IBAction)prev;
-(IBAction)next;

@end

#import "ResultViewController.h"
#import "JobAddSiteViewController.h"
#import "JobAddSiteAppDelegate.h"
#import "JSONKit.h"

@implementation ResultViewController
@synthesize listData;
@synthesize listLocation;
@synthesize listPostDate;
@synthesize listLogo;

NSInteger *countPage = 1;

NSArray *rows;
NSMutableArray *jsonResults;

NSMutableArray *tempArray;
NSMutableArray *tempArray2;
NSMutableArray *tempArray3;
NSMutableArray *tempArray4;

-(IBAction)done{

JobAddSiteViewController *second = [[JobAddSiteViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
[second release];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

JobAddSiteAppDelegate *ja = (JobAddSiteAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSString *strURL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bestitjobs.co.uk/totaljobs.php", ""];
NSData *nsData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: strURL2]];
NSString *dataResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tempArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tempArray3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tempArray4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bestitjobs.co.uk/appresults3.php?pg=%d", countPage];
NSData *nsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: strURL]];


NSDictionary* listDictionary = [nsData objectFromJSONData];
NSArray* people =[listDictionary objectForKey:@"jobs"];
for (NSDictionary *person in people) { 
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [person valueForKey:@"position"]];
    NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [person valueForKey:@"subcounty"]];
    NSString *str3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [person valueForKey:@"postdate"]];
    NSString *str4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [person valueForKey:@"logo"]];

    if(![str isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
    { 
        NSString *position = [person objectForKey:@"position"];
        [tempArray addObject: position];
    }

    if(![str2 isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
    { 
        NSString *subcounty = [person objectForKey:@"subcounty"];
        [tempArray2 addObject: subcounty];
    }

    if(![str3 isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
    { 
        NSString *postDate = [person objectForKey:@"postdate"];
        [tempArray3 addObject: postDate];
    }

    if(![str4 isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
    { 
        NSString *logo = [person objectForKey:@"logo"];
        [tempArray4 addObject: logo];
    }
}


//NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPhone", @"iPod",@"iPad",nil];

self.listData = tempArray;
self.listLocation = tempArray2;
self.listPostDate = tempArray3;
self.listLogo = tempArray4;


//[tempArray release];
[listData release];
[listLocation release];
[listPostDate release];
[listLogo release];
[super viewDidLoad];

}


- (void)dealloc {
//[tempArray dealloc];
[listData dealloc];
[listLocation dealloc];
[listPostDate dealloc];
[listLogo dealloc];
[super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

- (IBAction)prev{


}

- (IBAction)next{

[listData addObject:@"Mac Mini"];
[listLocation addObject:@"Mac Mini"];
[listPostDate addObject:@"Mac Mini"];
[listLogo addObject:@"Mac Mini"];
UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.view;
[tv reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.listData count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath       
*)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
    return 65;
}
return 65;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

UILabel *labelMain;
UILabel *labelLocation;
UILabel *labelDate;
UIImageView *image;


if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];


    image = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,3,80,62)] autorelease];
    image.tag = 4;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image];


    labelMain = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,3,200,20)] autorelease];
    labelMain.tag = 1;
    labelMain.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelMain];


    labelLocation = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,20,200,20)] autorelease];
    labelLocation.tag = 2;
    labelLocation.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    labelLocation.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelLocation];


    labelDate = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,40,200,20)] autorelease];
    labelDate.tag = 3;
    labelDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    labelDate.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelDate];

} 


[(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1] setText:[self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2] setText:[self.listLocation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3] setText:[self.listPostDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSString *imagePath = [self.listLogo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bestitjobs.co.uk/employers/logo/Files/%@", imagePath]];
//NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bestitjobs.co.uk/employers/logo/Files/%@", imagePath]);
image.image = uiImage;

return cell;

}



@end
```

### ERROR

2012-12-11 12:35:14.828 JobAddSite[674:207] -[UIView reloadData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e2d420
2012-12-11 12:35:14.931 JobAddSite[674:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView reloadData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e2d420'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00deb5a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f3f313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00ded0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d5c966 __*forwarding*** + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d5c522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   JobAddSite                          0x000039c1 -[ResultViewController next] + 262
    6   UIKit                               0x002db4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    7   UIKit                               0x004edcc3 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 156
    8   UIKit                               0x002db4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    9   UIKit                               0x0036b799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKit                               0x0036dc2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    11  UIKit                               0x0036c7d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    12  UIKit                               0x002ffded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    13  UIKit                               0x002e0c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    14  UIKit                               0x002e5f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x01743992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00dcc944 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d2ccf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00d29f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00d29840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00d29761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x017421c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x01742289 GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x002e9c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  JobAddSite                          0x00002af8 main + 102
    25  JobAddSite                          0x00002a89 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: What's the reason for the crash?

Comment: Can you add the crash error? If you add an exception breakpoint it will show you where it is crashing.

Comment: i have just added and edited the question with the error

Comment: does your `ResultViewController` is `UITableViewController` ?

Comment: `UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.view; [tv reloadData];` according to this line and the exception, it seems your view is not an instance of the `UITableView` class. you can check it inserting the following line in your code: `NSLog(@"%@", [tv class]);` and you will see what you are dealing with.

Comment: oh, I'm seeing in the crash log, your `self.view` is just simple `UIView` class, so something is definitely wring with your view-hierachy. why do you believe the `self.view` is an `UITableView`?

Comment: and why did you add cocos2d-iphone tag to your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.view;
[tv reloadData];
```

Why not simply use the *uITableView ivar that you created?  I think this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case anyone gets here through google...
Try wrapping the call to [tv reloadData]; in a main thread dispatch, like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [tv reloadData];
});
```